# Can I get my own question undeleted now that I can answer it?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

Months ago, I asked a question about where I could find a dataset of people's choices in an arbitrary binary decision task. I've recently begun collecting such data and posting it on my website, so I was going to answer my own question with my own dataset, but I think the question was recently deleted, presumably on the assumption that it would never get an answer. Now that I can answer it myself, can it be undeleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[done](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/13343/1511).

> Thanks for coming back to answer!

(I have to add text to keep the answer from being auto-converted to a comment.)

---

*edit* : for the record, you can undelete your own question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275753/2327328

Comment: That link is for answers, not sure if that works for questions that were deleted by the community user (abandoned questions)?